# Move a document from library after adding it

Tags: document-library, event-handlers, file-upload, event-receivers

I am using the ItemAdded event to fill in a metadata field.

In the ItemUpdated event (after submitting the file properties diagog) - I want to move the file elsewhere.

However, I get an error saying that the file was not found even though it is actually there. But I guess it's not registered as being there at this point in the sequence of events?!

My code is below:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemUpdated(properties);

       if (properties.ListTitle == "My Documents")
       {
           string fileURL = properties.ListItem.Web.Url + "/" + properties.ListItem.File.Url;
           using (SPSite siteSrc = new SPSite(fileURL))
           using (SPSite siteDst = new SPSite("http://dsidsw920"))
           using (SPWeb webSrc = siteSrc.OpenWeb())
           using (SPWeb webDst = siteDst.OpenWeb())
           {
               SPFile srcFile = properties.ListItem.File;
               SPFolder dstFolder = webDst.GetFolder("http://dsidsw920/Khurrams Documents");
               SPFile newFile = dstFolder.Files.Add(fileURL, srcFile.OpenBinary()); //Error occurs here!
           }
       }
   }

   public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       SPListItem ListItemAdded = properties.ListItem;
       if (!properties.Web.IsRootWeb)
       {
           string targetTerm = properties.Web.Name;

           if (properties.ListTitle == "My Documents")
           {
               SPWeb web = properties.Web.Site.RootWeb;

               TaxonomyField field = (TaxonomyField)properties.ListItem.Fields["WVTag"];
               Guid termSetId = field.TermSetId;

               //get term/s
               List<Term> terms = new List<Term>();
               TermStore termStore = GetTermStore(web);
               TermSet termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(termSetId);
               terms = termSet.GetAllTerms().ToList<Term>();

               bool siteNameFound = false;

               Term tagTerm = null;

               if (terms.Count > 0)
               {
                   foreach (Term term in terms)
                   {
                       if (term.Name == targetTerm)
                       {
                           tagTerm = term;
                           siteNameFound = true;
                       }
                   }
               }
               if (terms.Count == 0 || siteNameFound == false)
               {
                   tagTerm = termSet.CreateTerm(targetTerm, properties.Web.UICulture.LCID);
                   termStore.CommitAll();
               }

               TaxonomyFieldValue value = new TaxonomyFieldValue(field);
               value.Label = tagTerm.GetDefaultLabel(1033);
               value.TermGuid = tagTerm.Id.ToString();

               lock (LockObject)
               {

                   field.SetFieldValue(properties.ListItem, value);
               }
               EventFiringEnabled = false;
               properties.ListItem.Update();
               EventFiringEnabled = true;
           }
       }
       base.ItemAdded(properties);
   }
```

Your help appreciated thanks.

KS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fileUrl variable you used should be destination file url. Try this

```
byte[] fileBytes = sourceItem.File.OpenBinary();
bool overwritedestfile = true;
string destinationUrl = destinationList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + sourceItem.File.Name;
SPFile destinationFile = ((SPDocumentLibrary)destinationList).RootFolder.Files.Add(destinationUrl, fileBytes, overwritedestfile);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right doh! Now I just need to figure out how to transfer the metadata column values :S

Answer (score 1):

[SPFile.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms455020.aspx) is a lot better to use than reading the entire file and adding it.

Comment: Unless you are moving to another sitecollection - does it work when copying from subsite doclib to root site doclib (as per my scenario)?

Comment: No it's "internal"